# Is it possible to 'split' the content of a post in wordpress and display each chunk in a separate div?

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new to wordpress but my understanding is that the post is just one big article. you can insert images between paragraphs of text, but the flow will always be text, image, another paragraph, image etc.

I would like to use it for tutorials, and the layout I have in mind is to display every step as an image, with text on the left.

I know I can probably achieve this using images with legend and displaying the legend to the left. I was wondering though if there was a way to use the post (eg. the article itself) in this way?

Comment: The post editor has a "text" editor. You should be able to wrap content in divs however you want, using the text editor (instead of the WYSIWYG).

Comment: Depending on the theme you are using it would have 'class' options that would allow you to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Not sure how you'd do this in WP Core, but it sounds like a textbook use case for an [ACF Repeater field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)